# Imppossible to restore configuration with backup

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed a sonar's test serveur (same version, plugins, os, ... than the production) to test some Sonar upgrades.
I use the backup / restore function.

Everything work fine except for the quality profiles which do errors on the test serveur.

### The logs when I restore backuped files :

```
o.s.s.c.MetricsBackup  Disable user-defined metrics
o.s.s.c.MetricsBackup  Restore metrics
o.s.s.c.PropertiesBackup  Restore properties
o.s.s.c.RulesBackup  Disable rules created by user
o.s.s.c.RulesBackup  Restore rules
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Delete profiles
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile SIHM - GÃ©nÃ©ral
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile SIHM - GÃ©nÃ©ral
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile SIHM - GÃ©nÃ©ral
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile SIHM - GÃ©nÃ©ral
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile SIHM - Projets Intranet
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile SIHM - Projets Intranet
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile Sonar way with Findbugs
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile Sonar way
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile Sun checks
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile Sonar way
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile Sonar way
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile Sonar way
o.s.s.c.ProfilesBackup  Restore profile SIHM - Projets EAR
o.s.s.c.Backup  Backup restored
```

### The errors when I try to access to the enterprise quality profils (SIHM - xxxxx) :

```
ERROR o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade  Fail to render: http://xxxxx:9000/rules_configuration/index/10020
undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
        On line #11 of app/views/rules_configuration/_rule_note.html.erb

    8: %>
    9: <div id="<%= note_detail_div_id -%>">
    10: <div>
    11: <% if rule.description.strip.start_with?('<p>') %>
    12: <%= Internal.text.interpretMacros(rule.description) %>
    13: <% else %>
    14: <p><%= Internal.text.interpretMacros(rule.description) %></p>

    app/views/rules_configuration/_rule_note.html.erb:11
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2109:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
    app/views/rules_configuration/_rule.html.erb:46
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2109:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
    app/views/rules_configuration/index.html.erb:158
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1620:in `each'
    app/views/rules_configuration/index.html.erb:154
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2109:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in `_render_with_layout'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1252:in `render_for_file'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in `render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1328:in `default_render'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1334:in `perform_action'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2105:in `send'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
    file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
    file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
    file:lib/jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Regards,

Stephane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is buggy. That's why it was removed: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4887

Comment: Ok, so how to migrate the entire configuration from one server to another ?

Comment: It's not currently possible.

Comment: If I export only quality profiles, is it work or is it bugged too ?

Comment: I found the cause of the error : the backuped profile has custom rules based on the xpath squid rule, if I remove them from the backup rules I can succesfully restor and use them in the target environnement. Any Ideas ?

Comment: It shouldn't crash but your issue is related to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2055

Comment: ok, does it exist a way to delete manually the custom rules in the database to avoid of reinstall all ?